# Removing attributes from ArrayList created from a DOM Object, also removes them from original Document. What am i Doing wrong

Tags: java, list, dom, arraylist

I have a dom object like :

```
<Order OrderNo="123">
<Lines>
<Line LineNo="1">
<Details Quantity="1.0" Code="Apple"/>
</Line>
<Line LineNo="2">
<Details Quantity="1.0" Code="Orange"/>
</Line>
</Lines>
</Order>
```

I iterate through the Lines and out each line in a List like

```
List<Element> listOfRelatedLines = new ArrayList<Element>();
listOfRelatedLines .add(elOrderLine);
```

Now I iterate through the list and take each Line from the list.

```
for(Element elComponentLine : listOfRelatedComponentLines){

elComponentLine.removeAttribute("Code");

}
```

This removes the attribute Code from the original Document as well. Where am I going wrong here? What should I have done to retain the values in the original Document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting an element into a new array does not clone that element. So any changes to that element will still affect the original. You have to call `cloneNode` on the element in order to clone it. Do that at the time of adding to the array:

```
listOfRelatedLines.add((Element) elOrderLine.cloneNode(true));
```